# is there a way to limit access to s3 presigned url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a use case of allowing users to access remote file present in s3. Currently I am sending the pre-signed url in an email and allowing access. But I have a use case that is not met with this solution.
That being, in case the email containing the pre-signed url is forwarded to someone unintended, the forward recipient should not be able to access the file. Is there a way of authenticating an s3 presigned url by means of id/password. I am also open to a different solution using other AWS services as well to meet the use case.

Comment: I disagree, Yes, you can limit Access to presigned URL... follow The link: [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-presigned-url.html)

Answer (score 2):

Pre-signed URLs aren't particularly good for emails.

The intention with a pre-signed URL is that a user would authenticate to an application, then request access to some private content. The application would verify that they are permitted access, then provide a pre-signed URL to grant time-limited access to the content. Such access would normally be for up to 5-10 minutes.

As demonstrated by your scenario, there is an issue if somebody forwards a pre-signed URL to somebody else. This is normally not a problem because access time is limited. However, if a pre-signed URL is generated that has access for hours or days, it becomes more of a security issue.

**Solution:** Provide a link to your application. Users should authenticate, then be provided with a short-duration (eg 5-minute) pre-signed URL. This lowers the chance that other people can use the link.

Answer (score 0):

By default you **can't limit** who can use the pre-sign url. The entire purpose of pre-signed S3 urls is to enable access to your object to [anyone who has them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) for a limited time:

> **Anyone who receives** the presigned URL can then access the object.

If this does not suit you, you have few choices:

- **don't use pre-signed urls**, but instead create an IAM user which just the permissions to download the object. This will require login to the AWS by your recipients.
- use **password protected** 7zip or rar files that contain your objects. So instead of downloading objects directly, you provide pre-signed urls to password-protected archives.
- use **encryption** and share encrypted files. You clients will need to decrypt them.
- and many others

But ultimately they will be as save as your users' passwords, encryption keys or other types of protection you will implement.

Answer (score 0):

Create an endpoint on you application that checks the user session and than redirect to de pre-signed url

So in the email, send you application endpoint with file params like id or pure path.